# How to pass filtered Excel data as arguments to VBA function

Tags: excel, vba, parameter-passing

Say have a data table in Excel

```
| VarA | VarB | VarC
| A    |  1   | 3 |
| B    |  2   | 4 |
| A    |  3   | 9 |
```

I want to use the FILTER function to filter variables VarB and VarC using some criteria on VarA and send the results as arguments to a VBA function. For example, input this formula in a cell to use a function called Test:

```
=Test(FILTER(VarB,VarA="A"),FILTER(VarC,VarA="A"))
```

I tried this in VBA:

```
Function Test(vector1 As Object, vector2 As Object)
   a=vector1(1)
   b=vector2(1)
   Test=a*b
End function
```

and also tried passing vector1 and vector2 as Variants
but I get a #VALUE! error instead of the result of the multiplication

Comment: Pass them as variants and realize that they are being passed a 2D arrays.  So: `a=vector1(1,1)` and so on.